Apollo graphql fetchMore not hitting onError and causing an infinite loop of queries
I'm encountering a peculiar behavior when using fetchMore for pagination. I'm noticing that if the initial call to useQuery succeeds, but then a subsequent call to fetchMore fails, then onError is never called. Instead, onComplete is called and the response object will contain the result from the initial, successful useQuery call (presumably because it's cached by Apollo although I'm not sure of the specifics).
However, this leads to fetchMore being called infinitely. onComplete is where we call fetchMore, and since onComplete is being called instead of onError, and response will always exist, then fetchMore is just going to be called again and again. Is this a bug with Apollo? Or is there any way to force fetchMore to stop when it encounters an error?
EDIT: here's a codesandbox reproduction of the error: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/wonderful-tdd-4hhnpl?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.jsx%3A47%2C17
Below is a simplified version of my code. Essentially, the initial useQuery call is successful, but then I pass in garbage params into the fetchMore to force an error.
const { data, fetchMore } = useQuery(QUERY, { // this initial useQuery call works fine
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    variables: {
      params: {
        pagesize: 1,
      },
    },
    onCompleted: response => {
      console.log('response: ', resopnse); // this contains the data from the initial successful useQuery call
      if (response?.next) {
        fetchMore({
          variables: {
            params: {
              pagetoken: 'bogus', // bogus token to force an error
            },
          },
        });
      }
    },
    onError: err => { // this is never called even when fetchMore results in an error
      console.log('on error: ', err);
    },
  });

